# implement a pointer function to traverse the elements in the array

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I want to traverse the array element with pointer function by C. However, there's some limitations about doing the project.

Here is the array :

```
ary[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

I have to create three pointer-int-funciton like as follow :

```
int* begin();           
int* end();             
int* next();            
void printArray();
```

So, when I implement the funciton, I doing the way like this:

```
//define the begin function
int* begin(){
    int *index = &ary[0];       
    return index;
}
//define the next function
int* next(){
    int *count = ary;
    count ++;
    return count;
}
//define the end function
int* end(){
    int *index = ary;
    while (*index < &ary[5])
    {

        index ++;
    }
}
```

printArray function:

```
 void printArray(){
    
        for (begin(); next() <= end(); next())
        {
            printf("%d ",*next());
        }
    }
```

However, the next() function could not work, because using the upper code will enter an Infinite loop. I would like to code like could++.
I hope someone can figure the problem with me.

Comment: "*could not work like i++*". What does "could not work" mean exactly? And what is `i++` since there is no such code - do you mean `count++`? Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Yes! Kaylum. I mean count++. Sorry,  I seldom using the C.... And if I operate above the code, it will enter the unlimited loop

Comment: You need some sort of state that retains its value across calls of `next`. For example a `static` variable that points to the next array entry. (But note that such an implementation can only be called by one context at a time).

Comment: Before the definition of the `begin` function, put `static int *pointer;`. That creates a pointer that all three functions can see. Then write new definitions for those functions that use `pointer` to do what they are supposed to do.

Comment: @kaylum Thx Kaylum, actually could you give me a pseudocode to be the reference. I'm a very new beginner on C language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, so I have to create another variable outside the three function ?

Comment: Yes. `static int *pointer;` as a global variable. Then inside `begin` have `pointer = ary;` and in `next` have `pointer++;`.

Comment: But your `printArray` will still not work. It is calling `next` too many times. Every time `next` is called it will increment the pointer. Instead it should be `for (int * p = begin(); p < end(); p = next()) printf("%d ",*p);`

Comment: But `end` is wrong too. `while (*index < 0)` will not work. There is no guaranteed `0` at the end of the array. Reading past the end of the array will get an indeterminate value. Instead just do `return &ary[sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0])];` (or -1 for the array index if you want end to point to the last element rather than element after the last).

Comment: @kaylum Thank you so much.  The first time I want to create the application for inputing data into the ary at most 5 data, and I setting the negative number to be the end.

Comment: This looks like a school assignment.  Are you sure `int *next()` is the required function, and not `int *next (int *)`?  This would yield a much more sane `for` loop: `for (int *it = begin(); it != end(); it = next (it)) {...}`, and avoid a crazy solution with global or static variables.

Comment: @Perette Thank you. Actually, I enjoy practicing the C language. I used to code the Javascript before. So, I'm a beginner in C. I'm not familiar with pointer. That's why I want to do some different practice.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your declaration of int array should be `int ary[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, you missed the type.
2. Every time you call `next()` , you get a copy of ary's address to `count`, `count++` only increment the copied pointer, not the `ary` itself, so you will print infinite `2` on the screen.
3. You cannot increment the `ary` because it's an array not a pointer, or you will get error.

A simple way to print an int array like this:

```c
int main(){
    int ary[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *ptr = ary;
    while(ptr <= &ary[sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0])-1]){
        printf("%d ", *ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Modified code of your functions:

```c
int ary[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *ptr;

int* begin();           //set ptr to the address of ary, and return it
int* end();             //the memory space address of the last element of the array
void next();            //increment the ptr
void printArray();      //print out the values in the array

int* begin(){
    ptr = &ary[0];
    return ptr;
}
void next(){
    ptr++;
}
int* end(){
    //return &ary[4];
    return &ary[sizeof(ary)/sizeof(ary[0])-1];
}
void printArray(){
    for (begin(); ptr <= end(); next())
    {
        printf("%d ",*ptr);
    }
}

int main(){
    printArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh..it's a mistake, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Thx Jack. Actually, when I run upper code, I would like to use the sacnf to input the number. So maybe the just  3 number or 4 number, at most 5. However, if just have 3 number, it will print 2 zero when use the upper code. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Edward, I edited the code, it now can fit variable length of ary.

Comment: Thx. But if the scenario is only input 3 numbers, like int ary[5] = {1,2,3}, it will print 1 2 3 0 0 . So, how can i fixed to remove the zero, like results  1 2 3 ?

Comment: You mean you declared ```ary``` to 5-int array and only assign the first three values?

Comment: Yes!!! I just simplfied the question. The scenario is that we can input at most the 5-int in the ary. So maybe we just input the 3 number or 2 number or 1 number.

Comment: @Edward, if you want to print out length of numbers you scanned in, you don't need ```begin(), next(), end()``` to loop all array, just declare a variable ```length```, set ```length = i;``` before break.
In printArray(), use ```length``` to loop.

Comment: Thank you. That's I decide the senario to practice.  I think that I have to fix the end function to get the right end data from the ary. You can check my code on the top of the page. I'm appreciate you so much.

Comment: If in your case (from your post earlier) the ```ary``` can only contain non-negative data, you can initialize ```ary``` to all ```-1```, then in ```end()```, return the last non-negative value's position.